# Merging 2 rows into key=value string with BusyBox

Tags: awk, sed, sh, busybox

I need to write an sh script for embedded linux, which only has BusyBox (v1.30.1). I can use "sh", "awk", or "sed".

I have a script which receives 2 variables:

```
columns="usr sys nic idle io irq sirq"
points="2.2 4.5 0.0 93.1 0.0 0.0 0.0"
```

Both variables can have arbitrary number of measurements (from 1 to ~15).

I need to combine them to get a 3'd variable:

```
payload="usr=2.2, sys=4.5, nic=0.0, idle=93.1, io=0.0, irq=0.0, sirq=0.0"
```

Sh doesn't support arrays, so I can't iterate through "columns" and "points". Is there any way to achieve this task inside sh script (ideally) or with external commands available in BusyBox?

Edit: added what I tried as per James Brown request (obviously it didn't work as sh doesn't support arrays):

```
for index in ${!columns[*]}; do 
  payload="${payload} ${columns[$index]}=${points[$index]}"
done
```

Comment: Do `columns` contain shell meta-characters? If not, [something like this](https://ideone.com/BQR8rU) should work fine.

Comment: What does `I have a script which receives 2 variables:` mean? Scripts can read input from a file or a pipe, they can be passed arguments, and they have access to environment variables so - are those 2 environment variables your script is accessing or is it reading from a file or pipe to populate them or something else? Right now it feels like we're starting from half-way through your current approach to solving your actual problem and there's probably a better starting point.

Comment: @oguzismail, your solution works perfectly, and its quite simple to implement. I still don't understand how it works, though, I guess I'll just spend some time checking Bash Reference Manual.

Comment: @EdMorton, sorry, you are of course right. My script gets this variables through passed arguments. Each variable is enclosed in double quotes, like this: script.sh "column1 column2 column3" "point1 poin2 point3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Busybox awk`:

```
$ payload=$(busybox awk -v c="$columns" -v p="$points" '
BEGIN {
    n=split(c,cc)
    m=split(p,pp)
    if(m==n)
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            printf "%s=%s%s",cc[i],pp[i],(i==n?ORS:", ")
}')
$ echo $payload
usr=2.2 sys=4.5 nic=0.0 idle=93.1 io=0.0 irq=0.0 sirq=0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, your example is working just fine. Could you please explain what "i==n?ORS:OFS" means? I googled ORS and OFS, but still don't understand why you need ":" between and what this whole line means anyway. I guess it will also let me to separate values with comma if I figure it out.

Comment: It's called _conditional operator_, another way to write that (but not use _exactly_ as above) is `if(i==n) printf "%s", ORS; else printf "%s", OFS`. Above way it can be attached into a single `printf`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help! I changed it to (i==n?ORS:", ") and finally got what I need. Should I accept your answer as-is or you'll change it accordingly first?